# How to load texture in Open3D

Tags: python, 3d, open3d, 3d-model

I'm posting this even though a similar question exists: [How to add texture to a mesh in python Open3d?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879709/how-to-add-texture-to-a-mesh-in-python-open3d) as some classes and their definition have changed with v.0.16.0.

I have been trying to visualize 3D models in Open3D-Python by using the following code:

```
import open3d as o3d
model = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("nk1.glb")
model.compute_vertex_normals()
o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([model])
```

The issue is that even though the 3D model has texture, it's not being displayed in the visualization window. The model appears with a default grayish color.

Even though the model appears with color on other platforms[image: Model with color on other various platforms]

The same is not true in Open3D
[image: Model visualized in Open3D]
Using `model = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("cc.obj",  True)` isn't working for .obj models with .png texture files either

Here's the link to the 3D models: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Q1FcgdU-9mhpiD0uRT4atZIM-PvymyPw?usp=share_link